# Words starting with vowel "Y"?

Tags: vowels

Are there words starting with the letter "y" pronounced as a vowel sound and can be proceded with "an"?

Comment: I'm tempted to answer *an ypsilon* but in English it is *upsilon* so it would only work if quoting.

Comment: [***ympt***](http://www.wordsthatbeginwith.com/scrabble/y_is_only_vowel_words) - *to graft*. But it's a verb, so no ***an ympt***.

Comment: Another verb - yclept.

Comment: nouns starting with vowel y?

Comment: If proper nouns count, there’s “Ypres,” which is the English (from the French) name for the Belgian city known officially as “Ieper” in Flemish.  Under the “Museums and Galleries” section, [this *WikiTravel* entry for Ypres](https://wikitravel.org/en/Ypres) describes “Kattenstoet” (The Festival of the Cats) as a commemoration of  “**an Ypres** tradition from the Middle Ages [in which cats were thrown from the belfry tower of the Cloth Hall to the town square below](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tcldvjdwVgg).” (watch if you dare!)

Comment: *yperite,ylem*... Probably any word starting with *y* followed by a consonant.  Most of them are archaic or obsolete. In modern English, they are usually technical words.

Answer (score 3):

Some, but it's very uncommon. The chemical elements [**Yttrium**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yttrium) (*IT-ree-əm*) and [**Ytterbium**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ytterbium) (*ih-TUR-bee-əm*) come to mind as examples, in the sense of "an yttrium atom".

Comment: to be strict, though, one will hardly say "an Yttrium" )))

Comment: to be strict, though, that wasn't required by the question :)

Comment: If I remember correctly, those names derive from "Ytterby" so there's another proper noun.

Answer (score 1):

Middle English allows us "yghe" (eye) and "yren" (iron).  The first can easily be found as "[an yghe](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=n6oMtFrvg8wC&lpg=PA1209&ots=Ymdw3eDcew&dq=%22an%20yghe%22&pg=PA1209#v=onepage&q=%22an%20yghe%22&f=false)" in old books. The second is mostly used as an adjective (e.g. "[an yren smith](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=niiOyLHUdicC&lpg=PA278&ots=6bOOCwW-pH&dq=%22an%20yren%20smith%22&pg=PA278#v=onepage&q=%22an%20yren%20smith%22&f=false)"), however, "[an yren bounde cofre](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=p4yxAwAAQBAJ&lpg=PA95&ots=LhELjWqsPJ&dq=%22an%20yren%20bounde%20cofre%22&pg=PA95#v=onepage&q=%22an%20yren%20bounde%20cofre%22&f=false)" (an iron bound coffer) can be found too, which I believe designates "yren" as a noun. The OP simply asked for *can be proceded with "an"* so the designation as a noun isn't strictly a requirement, but I felt strangely compelled to try to meet that criterion.

However there are two animals that start with "y".  The "yllatron", another name for the "[agouara](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/agouara)" (crab-eating raccoon!) and the "ynambu", another name for the "[tinamou](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red-winged_tinamou)" (a South American bird, similar to a partridge).

So there are geniune modern English usages of "an yllatron" and "an ynambu".

Hence the answer to the question is "Yes".